# Formatting Value as Date in UNION ALL statement as 'MMYYYY'. One column is an varchar formatted as 'YYYYMM' and the other one is 'MMYYYY'

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I get both in a Date Format and in the same order formatted as 'MMYYYY' as 1 source file only has the month and year associated to when the file was processed? This will eventually be consumed into a report, to show the Forecasts v Actuals.

```
( select 
(RIGHT(BDX.Month,4) +''+Right('0'+
 CONVERT(varchar,
      CASE
        WHEN UPPER(LEFT(BDX.[Month], 4)) = 'SEPT' THEN 9
          ELSE MONTH(BDX.[Month])
          END
          ),2) 
         
        ) as MonthYear,
 SUM(TransactionPremium) AS Forecast, 
 SUM(AnnualPremium) AS AnnualPremium,
 SUM(P.PremiumWritten) AS Actuals
 from [dbo].[SRC_AD_BDX_Program_Production_vw] as BDX 
 LEFT JOIN [dbo].[MNL_Magic_LkupIndustry_vw] I on BDX.IndustryCode = I.IndustryDesc
 LEFT JOIN Dim_ProductMisc PM on I.IndustryCode = PM.IndustryCode
 LEFT JOIN Fact_Policy P on PM.ProductKey = P.ProductMiscKey
  WHERE ProgramName LIKE '%Sierra%'
GROUP BY BDX.ProgramName, BDX.Month

UNION ALL 

SELECT
CONVERT(varchar,CASE
WHEN Left(cast(D.MonthYear as varchar),3) = 'Jan' THEN '01'
WHEN Left(cast(D.MonthYear as varchar),3) = 'Feb' THEN '02'
WHEN Left(cast(D.MonthYear as varchar),3) = 'Mar' THEN '03'
WHEN Left(cast(D.MonthYear as varchar),3) = 'Apr' THEN '04'
WHEN Left(cast(D.MonthYear as varchar),3) = 'May' THEN '05'
WHEN Left(cast(D.MonthYear as varchar),3) = 'Jun' THEN '06'
WHEN Left(cast(D.MonthYear as varchar),3) = 'Jul' THEN '07'
WHEN Left(cast(D.MonthYear as varchar),3) = 'Aug' THEN '08'
WHEN Left(cast(D.MonthYear as varchar),3) = 'Sep' THEN '09'
WHEN Left(cast(D.MonthYear as varchar),3) = 'Oct' THEN '10'
WHEN Left(cast(D.MonthYear as varchar),3) = 'Nov' THEN '11'
WHEN Left(cast(D.MonthYear as varchar),3) = 'Dec' THEN '12'
END
+''+ RIGHT(cast(D.MonthYear as varchar),6)
,1) as MonthYear,
0 as Forecast,
0 as AnnualPremium,
SUM(P.PremiumWritten) as Actuals
FROM Fact_Policy P
 LEFT JOIN Dim_ProductMisc PM on PM.ProductKey = P.ProductMiscKey
 LEFT JOIN Dim_Date D on P.AccountingDateKey = D.DateKey
 LEFT JOIN MNL_Magic_LkupIndustry I on PM.IndustryCode = I.IndustryCode
  WHERE I.IndustryDesc LIKE '%Sierra%'
 GROUP BY I.IndustryDesc, MonthYear
 )
```

Sample Data:

- Program : ABC Company
- MonthYear : 202012 | 122020 <- 1st one is top query in 'YYYYMM' and other one is second query after the UNION ALL 'MMYYYY'
- Forecast : 1000.00
- Actuals : 950.00

Comment: please provide sample data

Comment: Added some sample data at the bottom of the SQL hope this helps